# Math question differential equations help?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have to solve the equation:
$$e^y (1+x^2)dy-2x(1+e^y)dx=0.$$
So what I do is:
$$ [e^y/(1+e^y)]dy = [2x/(1+x^2)]dx $$
I find the integral of both sides $\ln|1+e^y|= \ln|1+x^2| + C$,but the answer in my book is $1+e^y=(1+x^2)C$ and I dont get the same answer. Why?

Edit: How I found the integrals:

$\ln|1+e^y|= \ln|1+x^2| + C$  but the answer in my book is $1+e^y = (1+x^2)C $

Comment: Maybe you made a mistake finding the integrals. Show a bit more of your work, if you really want to know why you don't get the same answer as the book.

Comment: Ok, I will edit this!

Comment: You have written two different things and claimed that each one is the answer in your book. They can't both be the answer in your book. But maybe the point is if you have $\log Q+C$ and you exponentiate to get $e^CQ$ where $C$ is an arbitrary constant, then $e^C$ is also an arbitrary (positive) constant, so you can just write $C$ instead of $e^C$.

Comment: Oh sorry,I will edit this again :/

Answer (score 1):

$e^y(1+x^2)dy=2x(1+e^y)dx$, separate $x$ and $y$ terms, then $e^y/(1+e^y)dy=2x/(1+x^2)dx$,
$\frac{1}{1+e^y}d(1+e^y)=\frac{1}{1+x^2}d(1+x^2)$,

then $ln(1+e^y)=ln(1+x^2)+C$, 
each side $e^{ln(1+e^y)}=e^{ln(1+x^2)+C} \rightarrow 1+e^y=(1+x^2)e^C$ replace $e^C$ with another $C_0$.